# Adhoc iOS App crash - CFDataGetBytePtr

Tags: ios, crash, adhoc

I have a iphone app which gets bytes from image and does some manipulations. At the end, bytes are copied back to UIImage. When I test on 3GS, It works perfectly well. No crashes. When some of my friends test on 4S, it crashes in adhoc manner. I used testflight to capture crash report and symbolicate. Here is the code where it crashes. I used the same image of 4s to 3gs but again no crash. Does any one know how to find out the root cause and fix it?

Could it ever happen that when a UIImage is converted to CGImageRef, it returns different width and height??

```
-(UIImage *) CopyBytesToUIImage:(int*)img 
                               :(int) width
                               :(int) height 
{

    //(int*)img was build by extracting bytes from OriginalSourceImage
    CGImageRef inImage = OriginalSourceImage.CGImage;
    CFDataRef m_DataRef = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(inImage));  
    UInt8 * m_OutPixelBuf = (UInt8 *) CFDataGetBytePtr(m_DataRef);  

    int iStep,jStep;

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
    {
        iStep = i*width*4;
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
        {
            jStep = j*4;
            m_OutPixelBuf[iStep + jStep ] = m_OutPixelBuf[iStep + jStep +1] =    m_OutPixelBuf[iStep + jStep +2] = img.arr2D[i][j];

            //Test flight shows that it crashes during this assignment.
        }
    }   

    CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(m_OutPixelBuf,  
                                             CGImageGetWidth(inImage),  
                                             CGImageGetHeight(inImage),  
                                             CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(inImage),
                                             CGImageGetBytesPerRow(inImage),  
                                             CGImageGetColorSpace(inImage),                                          CGImageGetBitmapInfo(inImage) 
                                             ); 

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);  
    CGContextRelease(ctx);
    UIImage *finalImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    CFRelease(m_DataRef);
    m_OutPixelBuf = nil;
    return finalImage;

}
```

Here is testflight data

```
1.  0 MyApp 0x000cf6ae testflight_backtrace + 238
2.  1 MyApp 0x000d0398 TFSignalHandler + 264
3.  2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x3a63de92 _sigtramp + 42
4.  3 MyApp 0x0009e328 -[clsEditor CopyBytesToUIImage:::] + 176
5.  4 MyApp 0x0009e1c4 -[clsEditor Sketch:] + 596
```

Thank you in advanse.

Comment: You have a comment in the for loop that says this is where it crashes but you seem to have removed the code from within the for loop.  I doubt we can help you if we can't see the code that is actually failing.

Comment: Hello Mttrb - I have updated the code and put the assignment where it fails. Basically 2d array is grayscale while image is colored so I am just assigning the pixels.

Comment: Could it ever happen that when a UIImage is converted to CGImageRef, it returns different width and height??